# Edge Detection from image using python libraries and Contours Draw

Tags: python, opencv, edge-detection

Hellow everyone,

I am trying very hard to extract edges from a specific image. I have tried many many ways, including;

1. grayscale, blurring (laplacian,gaussian, averaging etc), gradient (sobel, prewitt, canny)
2. With morfological transformations
3. Even thresholding with different combinations
4. Even HSV convert and masking and then thresholding
5. Using Contour Methods with area thresholding

Except all of this, I have tried different combinations with all the above. BUT neither of the above, had an excellent result. Main  problem is still too many edges/lines. The image is an orthomosaic 2D photo of a marble wall. I will upload the image. Anyone have any ideas?

P.S The final result should be an image that has only the "skeleton' or/ shape of the marbles. 
[Wall.tif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AeCAb.jpg)

Comment: Edge detection and finding "skeleton or shape of marbles" are different tasks. Can you clarify the expected result with an output image?

Comment: If you don't get good results using the Canny detector, then the chance is that your input data doesn't lend itself to this kind of processing. Looking at your data though, I would recommend a Canny edge detector, followed by a Hough line detection. If the marble blocks are in all cases aligned like that then this might give you reasonable results.

Comment: shape of marbles is what I want to detect. I am saying if anyone want to try for a good result. Just take it as a challenge. @ilke444